# Equivalence between row operations and column operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My question is whether one can achieve, doing row elementary operation on a matrix, the same effect as doing column operation. For example, can I get a proportional column using only row operations? Is there a general method? Or at least, can I get an equivalent system? I accept that some columns may appear permuted after those row operations.

Comment: Have you tried a 2 by 1 matrix?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with small matrices but I can't find a way to generalize it.